# Service doesn't run on continuous background location tracking

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to track user location continuously even after they close the app. The service continuously stores location on DB and a wakefulintent starts a timertask to upload it to server. I have used

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(Utils.googleApiClient,
mlocationrequest, this);
```

on a service. I have declared service on manifest as

```
        <service
        android:name="com.projest.services.BackgroundService"
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:process=":Background">
        </service>
```

and called servicew on my main activity using

```
        Intent service = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
        startService(service);
```

but the service is not working. I couldn't see log.

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service implements LocationListener{

public static final String TAG = "BackgroundService";
Context context;
LocationRequest mlocationrequest;
private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec

public BackgroundService(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public BackgroundService(){
}

public void onCreate(){
    try{
    super.onCreate();
    if(Utils.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG,"inside onCreate");
    }catch(Exception e){
        if(Utils.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG,"problem oncreate");
    }
}

public int onStartCommand(){
    if(Utils.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG,"inside onStartCommand");

    if(!Utils.startGpsTracker)
    {
        Utils.startGpsTracker=true;
        toggleGPS(true);

    }

    buildGoogleApiClient();
    Utils.googleApiClient.connect();
    if (Utils.googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

 public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");
        if (Utils.latestLocation == null) {
            Utils.latestLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(Utils.googleApiClient);
            if(Utils.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG,"inside onconnected");
            try {
                storeGpsinDb();
                if(Utils.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG,"trouble opening storeGPS");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        if (Utils.googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(Utils.googleApiClient, mlocationrequest, this);
            if(Utils.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG,"inside startlocationupdates");
        }
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Utils.latestLocation = location;
    try {
        storeGpsinDb();
        if(Utils.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG,"inside onlocationchanged");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    if (Utils.googleApiClient == null) {
        Utils.googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this.context).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        if(Utils.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG,"googleAPIclient");
    }
    createLocationRequest();
}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mlocationrequest = new LocationRequest();
    mlocationrequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mlocationrequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
    mlocationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if(Utils.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG,"inside createlocationrequest");
}

 public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
     Utils.googleApiClient.connect();
     if(Utils.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG,"insise connectionsuspended");
    }

 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(Utils.DEBUG)Log.d(TAG,"inside onDestroy");       
        stopLocationUpdates();
        Utils.googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

 protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        if (Utils.googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(Utils.googleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private void toggleGPS(boolean enable) {
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(Utils.DEBUG)System.out.println("toggleGPS:" + provider);
    if (provider.contains("gps") == enable) {
        if(Utils.DEBUG)System.out.println("toggleGPS:enable true");
        return; // the GPS is already in the requested state
    }

    if(Utils.DEBUG)System.out.println("toggleGPS:enable false");
    final Intent poke = new Intent();
    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
            "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
    poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
    this.context.sendBroadcast(poke);
}

private void storeGpsinDb() throws IOException {
    if (!(Utils.latestLocation==null)) {

    }else{


    }
    // }
}

}
```

What mistake am I making
I am working two weeks on this.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define **android:stopWithTask="false"** in manifest.

the process(Threads) run from the service will stop working if your      app is removed from the recent apps. To ensure that your       processes(Threads) remains always in running condition you have to       Override onTaskRemoved() method and add code to restart Tasks like       below.

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
    restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());    
    PendingIntent restartPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1,restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    myAlarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartPendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```